# Render a simple text with Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I'm looking to build an api with a meteorjs app ,so I need to render juste a text , without any HTML.
is it possible with meteorjs ?

Comment: yes, if you use something like iron router, you can do a server side route and just directly write the response

Comment: or use https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

Answer (score 0):

so I looked Iron router, and it was easy to render a server side response
simply by placing this code in the server

```js
Router.route("path/view", function() {
  this.response.end("ok");
}, {
  where: "server"
});
```

to test on the browser simply http://localhost:3000/path/view will render just "ok"

I found this on https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/server-side-routes-with-iron-router/#tmc-what-is-a-server-side-route